# How to dynamically add values in "IN" in mysql WHERE clause?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, mariadb

I have written a query which will dynamically add parameters to that query.Following is the query I have written.

```
     var sql ="SELECT s.contactId,s.name,s.phone,s.isDistributor,s.distToBeStatus,l.id AS languageId,l.name AS languageName,l.languageCode,l.nativeName,l.countryCode,c.id AS cityId,c.name AS cityName,c.state,c.country 
FROM syncContacts s LEFT JOIN languages l ON s.languageCode=l.languageCode 
LEFT JOIN cities c ON s.cityId=c.id WHERE s.distId=? AND s.distToBeStatus=?
 AND s.isDistributor =? AND s.languageCode IN (?) AND s.cityId IN (?)
 AND s.ageGroupId IN (?) AND s.occupationId IN (?) AND s.traitsId IN (?)"

var parameters =['2',1,0,'1','1','1','1','1']
var rows = await connection.query(sql,parameters)
```

Currently I am developing an application in Node.js in Express, in which there is a feature for filtering a list of contacts with multiple filters.So I am creating the above query dynamically in accordance with the filters needed.For example if I need to fetch all contacts with languages hindi & english and with cities Banglore & Kochi. Then I have to add multiple values in IN(?) dynamically for both `s.cityId IN(?) AND s.languageCode IN(?)`.This will change as per the filter .So in the above code parameters will be generated dynamically.What I need is I want to add multiple values in IN(?).For example In the above code if I need result with multiple cities;how can I add multiple values in `s.cityId IN(?)` dynamically?Currently I couldn't add multiple values for one `IN(?)` query. The above code is working fine for one value in `IN(?)` query.

The raw query for the above filter would look like this.

```
SELECT s.contactId,s.name,s.phone,s.isDistributor,s.distToBeStatus,l.id AS 
languageId,l.name AS languageName,l.languageCode,l.nativeName,l.countryCode,c.id AS 
cityId,c.name AS cityName,c.state,c.country FROM syncContacts s LEFT JOIN languages l ON 
s.languageCode=l.languageCode LEFT JOIN cities c ON s.cityId=c.id WHERE distId="2" AND s.distToBeStatus="1"
 AND s.isDistributor ="0" AND s.languageCode IN (1,2)
 AND s.cityId IN (1,2) AND s.ageGroupId IN (1,2)
 AND s.occupationId IN (1,2) AND s.traitsId IN (1,2)
```

Please help me to find out a solution?Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you also add what will be the end actual query? just to understand.

Comment: Pretty sure [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/) can expand arrays given as placeholder values into multiple values in an `IN` clause.